# Circle CI angular Unexpected token )

Tags: angular, npm, continuous-integration, yarnpkg

I'm trying to set up a simple workflow for testing a sample angular project using Circle CI

I've tried with both yarn and npm but when it comes to running `ng <something>` I get the following error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng:26
  );
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
```

What i've tried

```
version: 2

jobs:
    build:
        working_directory: ~/angularcli
        # The primary container is an instance of the first list image listed. Your build commands run in this container.
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:6-browsers
              environment:
                  CHROME_BIN: "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                name: Install node_modules with npm
                command: npm install
            - save_cache:
                key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
                paths:
                    - ./node_modules
            - run:
                name: Install angularcli
                command: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest 
            - run:
                name: update angular circleci
                command: sudo ng update
            - run:
                name: Run unit tests with karma
                command: ng test
            - run:
                name: Build
                command: ng build
            - store_test_results:
                path: test-results.xml
```

also with yarn

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/repository
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:6-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: install-dependencies
          command: yarn install --ignore-engines
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: angular-build
          command: yarn ng build --prod --aot --no-progress
      - run:
          name: angular-test
          command: yarn test -- --single-run --no-progress
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-results.xml
          prefix: tests
      - run:
          name: angular-lint
          command: yarn lint -- --formatters-dir ./tslint-formatters --format junit -o tslint.xml
      - store_artifacts:
          path: tslint.xml
          prefix: lint
```

same error occurs with both attempts , I've tried calling ng update before anything else but to no avail , changed package manager to yarn on my project , tried with the --ignore-engine flag error remains the same

Comment: which node and typscript version do you use on your circle ci instance? Also on the side try to avoid `sudo npm install` calls

Comment: node v14.17.0  "typescript": "~4.2.4"